# Tricky Differentials Question

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization

Let variables x, y and z be linked by the two relationships:
$$
\begin{split}
f(x, y, z) &= −x^2 &+ y^2 &+ z^2  &− 1 &= 0\\
g(x, y, z) &= 3x^3 &+ y^3 &+ 2z^3 &− 6 &= 0
\end{split}
$$

Derive conditions on the differentials $dx$, $dy$, and $dz$ if the functions $f$ and $g$ are kept at these values. If $y = 1$, find the two points with values of $x$ and $z$ satisfying $f = g = 0$.

To be perfectly honest, I don't know where to start with this question. Never seen anything like it before. Any advice/ help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The second question seems easy: plug in $y=1$ to see from the first equation that $x = \pm z$ and plug both into the second...

Comment: @gt6989b Would the second question not require some form of working from the first part?

Comment: Not necessarily, seems my suggestion is quite straight-forward here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You treat $x,y,z$ as variables that depend on a fourth variable $t$, and differentiate the equation with respect to $t$.

For example, look at your equation $$-x^2+y^2+z^2-1=0.$$ Apply the differentiation $\frac{d}{dt}$ to both sides of the equation to see that $$\frac{d}{dt}(-x^2+y^2+z^2-1)=\frac{d}{dt}0,\\-2x\frac{dx}{dt}+2y\frac{dy}{dt}+2z\frac{dz}{dt}=0.$$ It looks like implicit differentiation, because it is.

Multiply the last equation by $dt$ to see that $$-2xdx+2ydy+2zdz=0.$$ You then do the same thing again for the equation $g=0$. I leave it to you.

In general, if you are given a function $F$ and an equation $F(x,y,z)=0$, the condition on the differentials is the equation $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}dz=0.$$ You can extend this idea to any number of variables.